# Mysqli fetch array return null

Tags: php, database, mysqli

Hello everyone I am having problems with mysqli syntaxes but when i finally managed to make a proper call script returns nothing.

```
$day = "2014-01-11 11:29:44";
$sql = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM vn_questions WHERE creationDate='$day'");
var_dump($sql);
```

It returns 13 row but with NULL length

`object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(7) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(13) ["type"]=> int(0) }`

```
while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{ 
    $res = '<div class="qOfDay">'.$data['question'].'<span class="autor">- '.$data['autor'].'</span></div>';
}
var_dump($data);
```

it return NULL .. why ? tell me please. And also someone explain me why mysql is going to be deprecated and replaced by complicated mysqli with terrible syntaxes... for basic users it is hell.

Comment: Try running the above query in sql first , i think there is no result matching your criteria

Comment: `while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($sql);{ ` There's a syntax error. Please copy and paste the code accurately

Comment: you can test with printing  echo "SELECT * FROM vn_questions WHERE creationDate='$day'"; 
then run the query in PHPMyAdmin to ensure that the query gets the result.

Comment: oh thx the ";" was a problem :D